# How can I measure the relative performance cost of different hashing methods in PHP?

Tags: php, testing, hash

I'd like to know how long each hashing algorithm takes on a particular system given different dataset lengths.

Comment: see the manual for microtime(), examples of timing code execution are given.

Comment: +1 for reposting as a question.  :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I whipped up this script.  I recommend playing with the $random_len value.  Differing values produces some interesting results.

```
<?php
    $random_len = 100; /* bytes */
    $time_begin = microtime(true);
    $table_html = '';

    $algos = hash_algos();
    $fh = @fopen('/dev/urandom', 'rb');
    $random = fread( $fh, $random_len );
    $time_rand = microtime(true) - $time_begin;

    foreach ($algos as $algo) {
        $begin = microtime(true);
        $hash = hash($algo, $random);
        $end = microtime(true) - $begin;
        $table_html .= '<tr><td>' . $algo . '</td><td>' . $end . '</td><td>' . $hash . '</td></tr>';
    }
    $time_end = microtime(true) - $time_begin;
?>  
<html>
    <style>body{font-family:monospace}td{white-space:nowrap}</style>

    <h1>PHP hashing algorithm execution time</h1>
    <p>Random data length: <?php echo $random_len; ?> bytes</p>
    <p>Random data elapsed time: <?php echo $time_rand; ?> seconds</p>
    <p>Total elapsed time: <?php echo $time_end; ?> seconds</p>

    <table border=1>
        <thead><tr><th>Algorithm</th><th>Execution Time (s)</th><th>Hashed Output</th></tr></thead>
        <tbody>
            <?php echo $table_html; ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

The PHP.net page for [`hash`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.hash.php) has some sample code in the comments that demonstrates how you can profile the various PHP hashing functions.

[Here is one person's recorded times](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.hash.php#89574), along with some sample code on how you can replicate the test.

Answer (score 0):

See http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.microtime.php.  Basically, something like this:

```
$input = "blah";
$start = microtime(TRUE);
for($i=0;$i<1000;$i++)
   sha1($input);
$end = microtime(TRUE);
print "Took ".($end-$start)." sec for 1000 sha1s."
```