# Encryption Routine to encrypt an 8-digit field into 16 (or more) characters

Tags: security, encryption

I have an 8 digit field that I would like to encrypt (I am not worried about decrypting it) into a 16 character (or more) field.  I need this so I can use the encrypted field to send to a reporting agency.

Comment: What is the reporting agency going to do with it? Also, what environment are you working in (C++, Python, PHP, etc?)

Comment: What, exactly, are you trying to achieve by "encrypting" the field? Must the mapping from 8 digit to 16 characters be one-to-one and onto? Are there any other requirements? It's critical for us to know these things in order to properly answer your question.

Comment: As others have pointed out too, this question is not specific enough. For example there is not way telling if encrypting the field as a single block with say Cast-128 meets the requirements.

Answer (score 1):

Since you don't need decryption you could hash it (irreversibly) instead of using encryption. In PHP you could do this with [hash](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.hash.php) and the `fnv164` hash algorithm, which returns a 16 character hash.

Also, there are several other hash algorithms that will produce greater than 16 characters. You can use [hash_algos](http://php.net/manual/en/function.hash-algos.php) to see what's available on your system. [Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8330160/1024808) a script to do that.

Comment: If we are indeed talking about crypography then the proposed hash is not secure (enough)

Comment: He mentioned nothing of security. Only that the field needed to be encrypted.

Comment: Encryption sounds like security to me. We aren't completely sure yet, hence the comments.

Comment: I disagree. Encryption is often used soley as obfuscation. And the comments are spot on to request more information, which is why I upvoted them. My answer is, however, "correct" until the question becomes more specific.

Comment: Nevertheless, fnv164 IS encryption. Whether it is "secure (enough)" requires more information.

Comment: By its very definition a hash is not encryption, and a quick check on Wikipedia tells me "Fowler–Noll–Vo is a non-cryptographic hash function created by Glenn Fowler, Landon Curt Noll, and Phong Vo.". So, NON.

Comment: You are certainly correct there. Pardon my mutual use of the terms. I focused on his "(I am not worried about decrypting it)" to suggest a hash. I've edited the answer to be more clear.

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing too much about the purpose behind this "encryption" here's what I'd suggest (based on some conservative and security-preserving assumptions about what your goals are):

1. Pick a random number. Call it `R`. The number should preferably be at least 32 bits long.
2. For every 8-digit identifier you have, form the string "`<digits of R><8 digit identifier>`".
3. Use some cryptographically secure hash algorithm to get the hash of the string formed in step 2.
4. Format the hash from step 3 as a string of hex characters.
5. Use the hex character string from step 4 as the identifier that gets reported to the "reporting agency".

The benefit of this scheme is that as long as you remember the value `R` you can always map every 8-digit identifier to the same hex character identifier. This may or may not be important in your application.

Of course, this scheme assumes that you never need to perform a revese mapping, and the agency doesn't want to decrypt the identifiers. In other words, it assumes your goal is simply to not give the agency the identifier I but an equivalent identifier I'.

Comment: Looks like a poor attempt at reinventing HMAC to me. What is the motivation behind this?

Comment: AN HMAC is very different and I do not claim the above to achieve what an HMAC does. The requirement I assumed in my solution - based on the minimal and confusing information the OP provided - that his intention was to do an one-to-one mapping from `ID` to `ID'`.

Comment: Yes. I agree that an HMAC is a different thing. An HMAC is a keyd hash done right. Your construction while attempting the same does not achieve this. Biggest problem is the small key (32 bits)

Comment: No, my construction *doesn't* attempt the same thing - the construction I describe is that of a time-tested and well-understood algorithm for generating salted password hashes to be stored in a database. And you will notice that I said that R ought to be "*at least* 32 bits long".

Comment: Your construction isn't state of the art for password hashes either. There one would typically iterate that hash and prepend the random R to the result. Of course, as long as the OP doesn't clarify the question it is hard to give a reasonable answer.

Comment: I never said it was "*state of the art*" and I would appreciate it if you'd stop putting words in my mouth.

Comment: So by "well-understood" you mean "known to be inappropriate"? Furthermore, for password hashing one would generally use a different R for each hash, but your answer might be misinterpreted as using the same R for each hash, which is also known not to be idea.

Comment: The algorithm is *well-understood* - your non-arguments to the contrary notwithstanding. As for appropriate, I would argue that if the assumptions I made hold, then it's perfectly appropriate. Do they? I don't know, since the original poster is MIA.